# How to move the label further from the side of a triangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

I have this code for a right triangle with tikz

```
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=3.3]
    \draw (0,0) coordinate(A) -- (1,0) coordinate(B) -- (1,1) coordinate(C) 
    -- node[left,pos=0.5](){1} (0,0) ;
    \draw pic["$\theta$",draw, angle radius=6mm, angle eccentricity=.6] 
{angle=B--A--C};
    \draw pic[draw, angle radius=3mm] {right angle=A--B--C};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And it produces the following image

[image]

I need to modify my code so that the 1 side label is a bit further from the hypotenuse. I like that it is positioned in the middle, but the distance from the label to the hypotenuse is what is bothering me. I would appreciate any help on this. I thank all helpers.

Comment: Instead of `[left]`, use `[auto]` or `[auto,']`.

Comment: @Symbol1 thank you, what does auto do?

Comment: It *auto*matically puts a node next to the line the node attaches to. It will use one of NW, NE, SW, SE anchors to guarantee that the node is not overlapping with the line.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out a simple solution. I just inserted spaces

```
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=3.3]
    \draw (0,0) coordinate(A) -- (1,0) coordinate(B) -- (1,1) coordinate(C) 
    -- node[left,pos=0.5](){1\, \,} (0,0) ;
    \draw pic["$\theta$",draw, angle radius=6mm, angle eccentricity=.6] 
{angle=B--A--C};
    \draw pic[draw, angle radius=3mm] {right angle=A--B--C};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: compare with the previous answer  where for distance  we have used  `right =1cm`  in the code line `\draw (3,0) -- node[right=1cm, red, thick, circle, draw]{a}(3,10) ;`

Comment: @jsbibra thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I would draw you image on the following (simple) way:

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone} % crops previewer canvas to image size
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, 
                quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, scale=3.3]
    \draw   (0,0) coordinate(A) -- 
            (1,0) coordinate(B) --
            (1,1) coordinate(C) to ["1" ']  cycle;
    \pic["$\theta$", draw, angle radius=7mm, angle eccentricity=.7] {angle=B--A--C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note, `'` is abbreviation for `swap`. It put edge label on its opposite side. As you can see, for placing of label is used `quotes` library, which enable concise writing of labels on edges.

Distances of labels from ege as well it other style options you ca control with `every label/.style = {label distance, inner sep, ...}`. For more details see Ti*k*Z & PGF manual, section *17.10.2 The Label Option*, page 250. In above proposed solution is considered default settings for label style.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A PSTricks solution only for either fun or comparison purposes.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=\dimexpr355pt/113\relax]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}
\pspicture(6,8)
    \pstTriangle[PointName=none,PointSymbol=none](1,1){A}(5,1){B}(5,7){C}
    \pstMarkAngle[MarkAngleRadius=1,LabelSep=.65]{B}{A}{C}{$\theta$}
    \ncline{A}{C}\naput{$1$}
\endpspicture
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `355/113` is the famous approximation of pi up to 6 decimal places. Such an accuracy is not needed by PSTricks actually.